# Python - How to change value of a declared variable in function , by using data from other function

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

In class, I declared a global variable "status"
Later I used that variable in first function "test_1", and assigned value **status=None**

In second function "test_481" I changed value to that variable **status=TRUE**

Now again my focus came to first function then I am still seeing **status** value as **NONE** , I am expecting value **True** here (how to do this?)

Please give detail explanation (as I am still learning stage) with sample code.

```
class Test_Selenium():
    global status1


    def test_1(self):
        #Selenium driver logic
        
        status1 = None
        if self.status1 == None:
            return self.test_481()
        elif self.status1 == True:
             print(
                    "User is asked for new authentication")

    def test_481(self):
        ##some logic##

        if (logic):
            print("User authenticated - Passed")
            self.status1 = True
            self.driver.quit()
            return self.test_1()
```

Comment: where did you declare it as a `global` var?

Comment: I declared under class

Comment: Note that the ``global status1`` and ``self.status1`` are not the same. You may want to revisit the meaning of ``global`` as well as how classes work.

Answer (score 0):

The global variable is not actually used in your code. Only the attribute (`self.status1`) is used. The variable with only be set if logic returns True. Also you should use the `init` method to initialize class variables.

Try this code:

```
class Test_Selenium():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.status1 = None  # starting value
        
    def test__init__(self):  #  needed by pytest ?
         self.status1 = None # starting value 

    def test_1(self):
        #Selenium driver logic
        
        if self.status1 == None:  # can also use if not self.status1:
            return self.test_481()
        elif self.status1 == True:
             print("User is asked for new authentication")

    def test_481(self):
        ##some logic##
        
        logic = True

        if (logic):  # must be true to set status1
            print("User authenticated - Passed")
            self.status1 = True
            #self.driver.quit()
            return self.test_1()  # recheck status

ts = Test_Selenium()
print(ts.status1)  # None
ts.test_1()
print(ts.status1)  # True
```

Output

```
None
User authenticated - Passed
User is asked for new authentication
True
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I am using pytest hence I changed the code like this: 

'class Test_Selenium():
    
    def test__init__(self):
        self.status1 = None  # starting value

    def test_1(self):
        #Selenium driver logic
        
        if self.status1 == None:  # can also use if not self.status1:
            return self.test_481()'

       When I am debugging seeing error at self.status1 == None as Attribute Error: 'Test_Selenium' object has no attribute 'status1'

Comment: Please see above comments ^^^

Comment: I don't think `test__init__` is needed but I added it to the answer. If the tester is creating the object correctly `__init__` should be called to initialize the `status` variable.

Comment: Note that ``self.status1`` is not a class variable (attribute) – it is bound to the instance. A class attribute would be ``Test_Selenium.status1``.

Comment: @MM - Good catch. The test script may need to be changed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, - As I am new to the python course, can you give some examples for the above code?

Comment: @Kartik I recommend you do a [basic Python tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). If you change ``__init__`` to ``test__init__`` and don't yet see what's wrong about it, there is no point in random people on the internet providing random examples.